# Display my var as HH:mm (javascript)

Tags: javascript

I'm writing code that will allow me to log my hours worked a little easier. I can get the minutes past a defined time to display but I can't seem to get the format on the output to be HH:mm, here's my code;

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Time Past Since 08:30</title>
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="60">
<script language="JavaScript">
var sd = new Date(); // Get system date (sd)
var sh = sd.getHours(); // Get system hour (sh)
var sm = sd.getMinutes(); // Get system minutes (sm)
wh = (08); // Specify work start hour (wh)
wm =(30); // Specify work start minute (wh)
var vctime = ((sh *60 + sm) - (wh *60 + wm)); // Get differnece for system and work start, this needs to display in hh:mm but isn't
document.write(vctime); // output
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Before you go to w3schools ;) know that the `language` attribute is long deprecated (I'd suggest you to avoid w3schools if possible)

Comment: @Erick Please note that W3Schools links are of poor quality (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com) and the link you posted doesn't help OP solve the problem. You comment also fails to elaborate anything about why the link would help.

Comment: Be careful of daylight saving time bugs. Keep in mind, on 2016-03-13 in most of the United States there were 7 hours between 00:00 and 08:00.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your result is in minutes, why not just use division to convert minutes elapsed into hours and then apply a modulus to extract the remaining minutes?

```
hours_since = Math.floor(vctime/60);
minutes_since = Math.round((vctime/60 % 1) * 60);  // Use num % 1 to extract the decimal and convert it to minutes.

console.log(hours_since + ":" + minutes_since);
```

If you need the leading "0"s in your result, just write a simple conditional to check if the values are less than 10:

```
hours_zero_prefix = hours_since < 10 ? "0" : ""
minutes_zero_prefix = minutes_since < 10 ? "0" : ""
console.log(hours_zero_prefix + hours_since + ":" + minutes_zero_prefix + minutes_since);
```

Comment: This is great, I gave this to a college of mine and they asked if is was possible to specify the "var wh" and "var wm" figures with an user defined input box in HTML but when I try this the figure is blown out i.e.

wh = document.getElementById('ih').value;
<input type="text" id="ih" value ="08"></br>

Any suggestions on that?  This was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using diff in the Moment.js library to handle this calculation. The library will clean up the daylight saving time issues you would have by trying to do this by calculating the difference between the start and end hours. It looks like you want the difference in minutes between a start time and now. To do this with moment:

```
//returns number of minutes, accounting for DST based on the time zone of the local machine
var min = moment().diff(moment(yourStartDateTimeInIsoString), 'minutes');
//converts minutes to hours, then adds remaining minutes
return Math.floor(min/60) + ':' + min%60
```